# How to determine what to charge for a first time student applying to be a gamification consultant?

Tags: price-per-hour, fixed-price

I went to a gamification conference in December. I met someone in HR from HCL. He gave his card and asked me to email him. I think he is offering me a job. His designation is "senior director talent acquisition". I am thinking of doing some freelance gamification consultancy work to get some money, which I can then invest in my startup. I was thinking of emailing him.

How do I determine whether to talk about fixed price or hourly? How do I determine how much I should charge?

Comment: What's your experience? What's your portfolio like? What's your minimum charge to live? Where are you located? Is it going to be employment or just contract work?

Comment: Hello user, welcome to Freelancing SE. I made an edit to focus your question more on the *why* and *how*. No one can tell you specifically how to charge, but we can definitely tell you what process one should use to charge. Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't know what the acronym HCL means...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> He gave his card and asked me to email him. I think he was offering me a job.

First of all you wait untll he actually invites you for the job.

To decide your income, you can consult with your friends, professors and try to get idea of how much at similar posts other peoples are making.

Choosing a fixed price or hourly depends upon which you and your employer are comfortable. Are you good in setting fixed price budget or you good in working hourly. You should discuss it with your employer as they may have some preference for hourly or fixed price jobs. In case of confusion, you can left it upon employer to decide and later change it when you are comfortable with other.